# updating tkinter window for text background changes

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to show a green or red background in the text field of the answer to the simple addition quizzer.
Currently in PyCHarm complains that:
    Entry.grid_configure(background = "red")
TypeError: grid_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
0

I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help is appreciated.
Here's the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class MainGUI:

def __init__(self):
    window = Tk() # Create the window
    window.title("Addition Quizzer") # Set the title
    #window.width(len(window.title()))

    self.number1 = random.randint(0, 9)
    self.number2 = random.randint(0, 9)

    Label(window, text = "+").grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = E)
    Label(window, text = "Answer").grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.firstNumber = StringVar()
    Label(window, text = self.number1, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    self.secondNumber = StringVar()
    Label(window, text = self.number2, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    self.entry = StringVar()
    Entry(window, textvariable = self.entry, justify = CENTER, width = 4, background = "grey").grid(row = 3, column = 2)


    Button(window, text = "Answer:", command = self.computeAnswer).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = E)
    self.result = StringVar()
    Label(window, textvariable = self.result).grid(row = 4, column = 2)

    window.mainloop() # Create the event loop


def computeAnswer(self):
    self.result.set(format(self.number1 + self.number2))
    if self.entry == self.result:
        self.displayCorrect()
    else:
        self.displayIncorrect()

def displayCorrect(self):
    # self.correctAnswer = "Correct"
    # Label(self.window, text = self.correctAnswer, background = "green", justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 5, column = 2)
    Entry.grid_configure(background = "green")

def displayIncorrect(self):
    # self.incorrectAnswer = "Incorrect"
    # Label(self.window, text = self.incorrectAnswer, background = "red", justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 5, column = 2)
    Entry.grid_configure(background = "red")

MainGUI()
```

Comment: All the class methods need to be indented under the class statement.  I leave that to you.

Comment: Limiting lines to 80 chars makes code much easier to read both there and pasted into an 80 char wide editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you had read and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help Center material, you would have reduced your code to the following, which still gets the same error message.

```
from tkinter import *
Entry.grid_configure()
```

The message refers to the fact that Python instance methods require an instance.  This is usually done by calling the method on an instance instead of the class.  Otherwise, an instance must be given as the first argument.  Consider

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(1)
list.append(mylist, 2)
print(mylist)
# [1, 2]
```

You need to save a reference to your Entry box.  Change

```
    Entry(window, ..., background = "grey").grid(...)
```

to

```
    self.entry = Entry(window, ..., background = "grey").grid(...)
```

I do not know if calling .grid_configure(background=color will do what you want.
This will, I am sure.

```
    self.entry['background'] = 'red'
```

Comment: If you do not understand my answer, which is correct, read the section on calling methods of the Python Tutorial that comes with CPython.